# Changing font colour on locked text box

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, textbox

I am a newbie with VBA, so please be patient with me. I have a text box I don't want the user to modify directly only through user form. But if I set text box to enabled false then the font colour changes to default grey, which I don't want because it does not look good in terms of design (I generate PDF files from there) so my question is is there any possibility to change this locked text box font colour to something else for example blue or is it standard and cannot be manipulated? Thanks

I tried ChatGPT and various sets of VBA codes but that changed only the colour of text box when it was enabled=True, not when enabled=false.

Comment: Use a label instead?

Comment: One way to accomplish this task is to place the textbox in a frame (removing the border and caption) and then disabling the frame instead of the textbox.  Visually it looks like the textbox is disabled but you can manipulate the forecolor as needed.

Comment: If you don't want the user to change the text content directly, you could use a label instead of a textbox.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.